# the lib libxtables.so.5 exists.but remind libxtables.so.5 is required

Tags: linux, iptables, openwrt

```
    root@OpenWrt:~# ldd /usr/sbin/iptables
    libip4tc.so.0 => /mnt/sdc1/opt/usr/lib/libip4tc.so.0 (0x77460000)
    libxtables.so.5 => /usr/lib/libxtables.so.5 (0x7744a000)
    libdl.so.0 => /lib/libdl.so.0 (0x77436000)
    libm.so.0 => /lib/libm.so.0 (0x77411000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x773ee000)
    libc.so.0 => /lib/libc.so.0 (0x77382000)
    ld-uClibc.so.0 => /lib/ld-uClibc.so.0 (0x77476000)
root@OpenWrt:~# iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING   -p tcp -s 192.168.1.103 --dport 
80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 8087
iptables: target "REDIRECT" has version "libxtables.so.4", but "libxtables.so.5" is required.
root@OpenWrt:~# ls /usr/lib/libxtables* -la
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            19 Feb 29  2012 /usr/lib/libxtables.so -> libxtables.so.5.0.0
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            19 Feb 29  2012 /usr/lib/libxtables.so.5 -> libxtables.so.5.0.0
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root         21980 Feb 29  2012 /usr/lib/libxtables.so.5.0.0
```

I want to run iptables on openwrt router.but "libxtables.so.5" is required.and I find that libxtables.so.5 already exist.
is anybody tell me how to resolve this problem.
Thanks.

Comment: What's the output of `ldd /sbin/iptables`?  You probably have a shadowing library in `/lib/libxtables.so.4`.

Comment: thanks for your reply.and I attached the output of idd /user/sbin/iptables.please help check that
https://www.dropbox.com/s/8u86vgk7eerkug8/stackoverflow-iptables.png.
I am blocked by this problem

Comment: A copy/paste of the output would be much preferred to an image.  The output indicates that `ldd` resolves to `/usr/lib/libxtables.so.5` so either your problem is gone, or you run `iptables` in a different environment.  If you have `iptables` as a module, did you try unloading and reloading?

Comment: Anyway, this is off-topic for Stackoverflow; I have nominated for migration to http://serverfault.com/

Comment: I am sorry for attaching the image,because  the output text display ugly in the comment.and how can I find this topic in serverfault.com

Comment: You can edit your question to include additional information. Flag for moderator attention to request a move; mention that you are the author of the question.

Comment: The only error message I see is the `Bad argument` and I don't know how you think that has anything to do with `libxtables.so.5`. It's a bad argument because you put a space between the double-dash of `--dport`

Comment: I am sorry that i made a mistake.and I update the topic above.